# Symbols not displaying in a knitr document for different users

Tags: r, latex, knitr, octal

I'm working on a knitr document with a colleague. The script is stored on a shared drive but we each have our own installations of R, LaTeX etc.

When I compile the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

<< pract >>=

x <- "\247"

x
@


\end{document}
```

I get this output:

[image]

But when my colleague compiles the same code he gets this output:

[image]

Can anyone explain why the symbol displays when I compile the code but not my colleague? As far as we can tell we are using the same versions:R 3.2.2, MikTex 2.9 and knitr 1.11

Update: Our system locales appear to be the same:

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  
    LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252       
    LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252  

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
    LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    
    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252     
    LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Comment: Are you using the same preambles?

Comment: You two may have different system locales. Print out `sessionInfo()` and compare.